# Counting Problem; Discrete Structures

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have forgotten a lot of the counting portion of my discrete structures course and need some explanations how to count, maybe some general strategies on counting.

Some example questions I need explaining are

3. What is $\sum^{45}_{k=0}\binom{45}{k}(-3)^{2k}$

a)$(-2)^{45}$

b) $4^{45}$

c)$(-8)^{45}$

d)$10^{45}$

4. Consider a group of 8 people, consisting of Simon, John, and 6 other people. How many
   ways are there to arrange these 8 people on a horizontal line such that Simon and John are
   standing next to each other? (The order on the line matters and Simon is either to the left
   or to the right of John.)

a)$7*6!$

b) $2*7*6!$

c) $8*6!$

d) $2*8*6!$

I feel like 4 is B) but I'm not sure.

I havn't got a clue for 3.

if anyone can help explain these questions to me that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > A password consists of 28 characters, each character being a lowercase letter. A password must contain exactly one vowel. How many passwords are there?

I think we covered this in a prior thread of yours. :-)

> > Consider a group of 8 people, consisting of Simon, John, and 6 other people. How many ways are there to arrange these 8 people on a horizontal line such that Simon and John are standing next to each other? (The order on the line matters and Simon is either to the left or to the right of John.)

Group Simon and John as one object. Call this object $T$. So we permute $7$ objects. Then we have to permute Simon and John. So we take $7! * 2$ as our answer. Note $7 * 6! = 7!$.

I can't help you with (3), but hopefully this gets you going in a better direction. Make sure to give these problems a try first as well. That way, we can help you figure out if you are thinking about these problems correctly. Best of luck!